# How to create jenkins ssh key credentials using ansible?

Tags: jenkins, ansible, credentials

I'm trying to create sshkeycredentials in jenkins using ansible uri module.

```
- name: Add credential to Node
  uri:
    url: "http://{{ jenkins_hostname }}:{{ jenkins_http_port }}{{ jenkins_url_prefix }}/credentials/store/system/domain/_/createCredentials"
    user: admin
    password: admin
    method: POST
    status_code: 302,200
    body_format: form-urlencoded
    force_basic_auth: true
    headers:
      Jenkins-Crumb: "{{ crumb.content.split(':')[1] }}"
      Cookie: "{{ crumb.cookies_string }}"
    body: |
      json={
        "": "0",
        "credentials": {
        "scope": "GLOBAL",
        "id": "jenkins_linux_slave1_auth",
        "username": "automation",
        "password": "",
        "privateKeySource": {
          "stapler-class": "com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.sshcredentials.impl.BasicSSHUserPrivateKey$DirectEntryPrivateKeySource",
          "privateKey": "{{ key_file['content']|b64decode|replace('\n', '') }}"
        },
        "description": "Jenkins Linux Slave1 Authentication",
        "stapler-class": "com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.sshcredentials.impl.BasicSSHUserPrivateKey",
        "$class": "com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.sshcredentials.impl.BasicSSHUserPrivateKey"
        }
      }
```

But it didn't worked.It seems new line characters are added automatically to private_key while submitting the same to api

**Error message:**

```
fatal: [x.x.x.x]: FAILED! => {
    "cache_control": "no-cache,no-store,must-revalidate",
    "changed": false,
    "connection": "close",
    "content_length": "10191",
    "content_type": "text/html;charset=utf-8",
    "cross_origin_opener_policy": "same-origin",
    "date": "Mon, 19 Apr 2021 12:43:19 GMT",
    "elapsed": 0,
    "expires": "0",
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "attributes": null,
            "body": "json={\n  \"\": \"0\",\n  \"credentials\": {\n  \"scope\": \"GLOBAL\",\n  \"id\": \"jenkins_linux_slave1_auth\",\n  \"username\": \"automation\",\n  \"password\": \"\",\n  \"privateKeySource\": {\n    \"stapler-class\": \"com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.sshcredentials.impl.BasicSSHUserPrivateKey$DirectEntryPrivateKeySource\",\n    \"privateKey\": \"\"b3BlbnNzaC1rZXktdjEAAAAABG5vbmUAAAAEbm9uZQAAAAAAAAABAAABlwAAAAdzc2gtcn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\\ncHV0ZS5pbnRlcm5hbAECAwQFBgc=\\n\"\"\n  },\n  \"description\": \"Jenkins Linux Slave1 Authentication\",\n  \"stapler-class\": 
    "msg": "Status code was 500 and not [302, 200]: HTTP Error 500: Server Error",
    "redirected": false,
    "referrer_policy": "same-origin",
    "server": "Jetty(9.4.38.v20210224)",
    "status": 500,
    "url": "http://localhost:8080/credentials/store/system/domain/_/createCredentials",
}
```

Using surp to get the key content as below

```
- name: Read the ssh key file content
  slurp:
   src: /tmp/id_rsa
  register: key_file
```

key file content as below:

```
b3BlbnNzaC1rZXktdjEAAAAABG5vbmUAAAAEbm9uZQAAAAAAAAABAAABlwAAAAdzc2gtcn
NhAAAAAwEAAQAAAYEAvI4R2onsiDkN3ZKS46kJcMDMKvCaShQV6go6cddw2t6vyRa6Epp7
Ti/LifK4etnNfcD1HA0GPmqkh7V4/NX1zMvUlfoBAqckT3m3q3Qa8NThO3R0VEV9P4Q/No
t3Q2r2QyIyNnJ4dEAyI8mT7rPyJ8bXatP+l0/exZFRGHo92MYp8yde7WPjiCupF5fu0qZE
cHV0ZS5pbnRlcm5hbAECAwQFBgc=
```

if i remove quotes in private_key: "" then error as below

```
"privateKey\": b3BlbnNzaC1rZXktdjEAAAAABG5vbmUAAAAEbm9uZQAAAAAAAAABAAABlwAAAAdzc2gtcn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\ncHV0ZS5pbnRlcm5hbAECAwQFBgc=\n\n
```

Could you please help to resolve this issue

Comment: It would help to see you initial key file. It would also help to see you get the content (although I'm pretty sure you `slurp`'ed it from a remote server...). Meanwhile, the most obvious problem is that your data start and ends with a double double-quote (e.g. => "\"privateKey\": \"\"b3BlbnNza......")

Comment: added the surp and key details

Comment: did you try to fix the double-double quote ?

Comment: yes tried but no luck

Comment: added the key content after removed the double quotes

Comment: Well now you have no quotes at all which is not a valid json either.

Comment: how to fix this.Any idea?

Comment: by putting only one double-quote in front and one after the value....

Comment: fixed the issue by using lookup module and register the content in a varibale and used the result.stdout.But now getting error as - Caused by: java.io.IOException: PEM problem: it is of unknown type. Supported algorithms are :[ssh-ed25519, ecdsa-sha2-nistp521, ecdsa-sha2-nistp384, ecdsa-sha2-nistp256, rsa-sha2-256, rsa-sha2-512, ssh-rsa, ssh-dss] in jenkins slave agent launch